# Network printer driver install for non-admins running Win7 and no print server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I'm trying to configure a GPO setting to allow non-admins the ability to add a network printer. So far I've set the "Devices: Prevent users from installing printer drivers" to disabled and Enabled the "Point and Print Restrictions". Also under that setting, I've set the "When installing drivers.. and When updating drivers..." options to "Do not show warning or elevation prompt".

Ran gpupdate /force on my Win7 client, rebooted for safe measures, ran gpresult /r to confirm the GPO was applied. While attempting to add a printer I am still prompted for an admin password on a non-local admin user account.

I also have a windows 10 pro client machine in the same OU as the Win7 box and i can add the printer just fine with no admin prompts and using the same non-admin account. We don't have any print servers in our environment since we only have about 5 printers in the office. I'm not sure if the Point and Print restriction policy only applies if you actually have a print server on the network.

We're running all Windows Server 2012 R2 boxes. I've also tried enabling the "Allow non-admininstrators to install drivers for these device setup classes" and supplied the GUID for printers. Still no changes so I'm all out of ideas. I would like to have it working for both Win7 and Win10 clients because although we have a small windows environment theres a mix of win7 and win10 clients. Anyone have any other thoughts on what to check?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it's a really weird issue. Looks like Point and Print is only in effect when you actually use a print server. I happen to be researching and my laptop running Win7 was idling for 2-3mins and it suddenly just started downloading the drivers and the printer was added successfully. Even a test print went through.

As a test, I disabled all other settings except the "Prevent printer driver installs" policy, ran the gpupdate /force command and rebooted again. I was still able to install different printers. The only thing i noticed was that when I initially added the printer, I was prompted with the UAC prompt for an admin password. If you cancel out of that box, you see a PnPX Device Association UAC box. Here is where I happen to idle for 2-3mins and then my laptop just started downloading and installing the print drivers. I'm not really sure if this is a solution per se but it seems to work by just waiting a few mins. I've googled around and looks like their isn't a specified device GUID for PnPX so I settled for this